# jquery not working in asp.net mvc after publishing to localhost

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I've built an mvc application which contains some jquery code. When I run the app from my ide, everything works perfectly. When I publish to the server and open the page, the jquery does not work. I get object expected errors.

i am not getting anything in the page,it shows error in loading dhtmlxsheduler.js
can you help me out

Comment: Can you show us the line where you are referencing your jquery library? Could it be that your js files are not a apart of your project and are not published to the server?

Comment: Please provide a better description: copy/paste the error, provide some code samples, etc. Also, what browser? Do you have a script blocker active? If so, make sure localhost (or wherever you are pulling jQuery from) is allowed. All in all, your question is very vague - lacking in details.

Comment: show the line of html code where you reference `dhtmlxsheduler.js` and show a screenshot of windows explorer showing the location of the js file (path)

Answer (score 0):

You issue is most likely due to the way you are defining the path to the JavaScript file you are loading.

Make sure that you use a **relative path**, and not an absolute path when calling the file source.

If you have runat="server" you can also use the ~ operator, which ASP.Net translates to your home directory.

Read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your links to the .js files are broken. See the source code of your pages in your browser, and check the  tag's src attribute. It must be pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: function init() {

scheduler.config.xml_date = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i";
Uncaught ReferenceError: scheduler is not defined
var newdate = new Date();
var month = newdate.getMonth();
var year = newdate.getYear();
scheduler.init("scheduler_here", new Date(year, month, 1), "month");
scheduler.load("/Calendar/Data" );

var dp = new dataProcessor("/Calendar/Save");
dp.init(scheduler);
dp.setTransactionMode("POST", false);
}
</script>
</head>

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: scheduler is not defined this error i am getting in browser

Answer (score 0):

My guess is removing `../` do you have iis express? or development server? or iis?

Or use a CDN like this one from Google:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can anyone help me i am noting getting my answer properly for any of the solution above

Comment: As I said before: show the line of html code where you reference dhtmlxsheduler.js and show a screenshot of windows explorer showing the location of the js file (path)